# C++ read a file line by line but line type is CString or TCHAR

Tags: c++, file, file-io, cstring

I get the following example

```
    CString line[100];

    //string line;
    ifstream myfile (_T("example.txt"));
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
       while ( getline (myfile,line) )
       {
          cout << line << '\n';
       }
       myfile.close();
     }
```

How does that "line" can stored values ​​to type CString or TCHAR. I get an error like this:

> error C2664: '__thiscall std::basic_ifstream >::std::basic_ifstream >(const char *,int)'

Please help me :)

Comment: Read to std::string (std::string line;) and then convert to CString how MSDN suggests - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: can you give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this statement:

> ```
> CString line[100];
> ```

defines an *array* of 100 `CString`s: are you sure you want that?

Or maybe you just want *one* `CString` to read each line into?

```
// One line
CString line;
```

An option you have is to read the lines into a `std::string`, and then convert the result to `CString`:

```
string line;
ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
{
   while (getline(myfile, line))
   {
      // Convert from std::string to CString.
      //
      // Note that there is no CString constructor overload that takes
      // a std::string directly; however, there are CString constructor
      // overloads that take raw C-string pointers (e.g. const char*).
      // So, it's possible to do the conversion requesting a raw const char*
      // C-style string pointer from std::string, calling its c_str() method.
      // 
      CString str(line.c_str());

      cout << str.GetString() << '\n';
   }
   myfile.close();
}
```

Comment: I got an error: error C2039: 'GetString' : is not a member of 'CString', how to fix it?

Comment: @MyrdaSahyuti: What compiler are you using?? `GetString()` has been a member of `CString` at least since VS2005. Anyway, try `cout << static_cast<const TCHAR*>(str) << '\n'`.

Comment: I am using visual c + + 6.0

Comment: @MyrdaSahyuti: I supsected that :)

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd parameter of `std::getline()` requires a `std::string`, so use the `std::string` first, then convert it to a `CString`

```
string str_line;
ifstream myfile (_T("example.txt"));
if (myfile.is_open())
{
   while ( getline (myfile, str_line) )
   {
      CString line(str_line.c_str());
      cout << line << '\n';
   }
   myfile.close();
 }
```